# Code is returning zero from a mathematical expression

Tags: c++, math, factorial

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;  

int Factorial_of(int n)
{
    int fact = 1, i;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    fact = fact * i;
    return fact;
}



int main()
{
    cout << Factorial_of(4) / (Factorial_of(10) * Factorial_of(abs(4-10))) << endl;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is printing 0?

---

### Update:

After changing the code based on **@M. Twarog**'s answer, it is outputting "9.18577e-009" now, Does anyone know why?

Comment: Remember you are doing integer division. The result is an integer, meaning any decimal part is thrown away. 1/2 is 0 but 1.0 / 2 = 0.5 because the latter using double.

Comment: You also are missing a << before the endl

Comment: strongly suggest that you dont cram it all on one line, assign `Factorial_of(4)` to `int fac4` etc. Then cout each one. THis will help you see whats going on

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;  

double Factorial_of(int n)
{
    double fact = 1;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    fact = fact * i;
    return fact;
}



int main()
{
    double res=Factorial_of(4) / (Factorial_of(10) * Factorial_of(abs(4-10)));
    cout<<res;
}
```

There are some errors/mistakes . First for division always go with double variable. And Your code is returning value in point so return type should be double. Also you miss `<<` in `cout` statement before `endl`.

Comment: There are some errors/mistakes . First for division always go with double variable. And Your code is returning value in point so return type should be double.  (error) Also you miss << in cout statement before endl.

Comment: Note: computing the factorial in floating point will generate the wrong results for many factorials. There shouldn't be much of a problem in this case since the typical 32 bit `int` fits easily in a `double` without imprecision but one never really knows when an operation could insert a subtle error and with factorials, even subtle errors get large quickly..

Comment: It is currently outputting "9.18577e-009" so I think there may still be a mistake

Comment: The answer is right. "9.18577e-009" Answer is in scientific floating-point notation

Answer (score 1):

I can explain the output you get after fixing things: its the right answer

[image]